# Transparent list items in JQM collapsible

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the list items in a collapsible to have a transparent background, but I am having some trouble. Also, I am doing this in xcode for an iOS app through phonegap. The markup..

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" id="testy" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d">
 <h4>Heading</h4>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So right now you have a regular collapsible, nothing special. Instead of the li's being white I want them to be transparent. I was able to manipulate the background-color this way with css..

```
#testy ul li .ui-btn-inner {
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

I can change the color, but I can't get it to be transparent..so anyone know what I am doing wrong? I was able to make the header transparent with this css...

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn {
  background:transparent !important;
  border:none !important;
  border-color:black;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  text-shadow:none;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xPzwM/7/)

Thanks again!

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/udhtj/

Comment: Omar-I think that's it! Let me play around with it some more to make sure.